# Fatal error: Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::read() in E:\xampp\htdocs\rss\rss_url.php on line 13

Tags: php, xml, rss

Iam trying to parse rss feed from particular url...
here is my php file

```
<?php
//define ('XMLFILE', dirname(__FILE__) . '/editorial.rss');
$file = 'https://omni642stitches:6sT42nCd@cms.performgroup.com/cms/mrss/feed/editorial.rss';
$items = array ();
$i = 0;

//$xmlReader = new XMLReader();
$xmlReader=simplexml_load_file($file);

$isParserActive = false;
$simpleNodeTypes = array ("title","link", "description", "media:title");

while ($xmlReader->read ())
{
    $nodeType = $xmlReader->nodeType;

    // Only deal with Beginning/Ending Tags
    if ($nodeType != XMLReader::ELEMENT && $nodeType != XMLReader::END_ELEMENT)
    {
        continue;
    }
    else if ($xmlReader->name == "item")
    {
        if (($nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT) && $isParserActive)
        {
                $i++;
        }
        $isParserActive = ($nodeType != XMLReader::END_ELEMENT);
    }

    if (!$isParserActive || $nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT)
    {
        continue;
    }

    $name = $xmlReader->name;

    if (in_array ($name, $simpleNodeTypes))
    {
        // Skip to the text node
        $xmlReader->read ();
        $items[$i][$name] = $xmlReader->value;
    }
    else if ($name == "media:content")
    {
        $items[$i]['media:content'] = array (
                "url" => $xmlReader->getAttribute("url"),
                "width" => $xmlReader->getAttribute("width"),
                "height" => $xmlReader->getAttribute("height")
        );
    }
}

var_dump ($items);


foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
   <li> <a href="<?php echo $item['link'] ?>"><?php echo $item['title'] ?></a></li>
<?php }
?>
```

iam getting the above error but if i specify the path as stored rss file lik below

```
<?php
define ('XMLFILE', dirname(__FILE__) . '/editorial.rss');

$items = array ();
$i = 0;

$xmlReader = new XMLReader();
$xmlReader->open (XMLFILE, null, LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
```

everything is working fine... kindly help me with this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `read()` does not exist in the `SimpleXMLElement` class, see http://nl.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php . You might want to use the `children()` method

--- edit BTW the function `simplexml_load_file()` does not return a `XMLReader` instance, but a `SimpleXMLElement` instance, see also http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Comment: And it would just take a lookup on the manual to find that out without asking for help on SO

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of XMLReader
So you have to uncomment the following line:

```
//$xmlReader = new XMLReader();
```